# CORS error when sending GET to localhost from file:// URL via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, localhost

I have a server running on my computer and simple .html file with button for receiving data from server.

It uses Javascript's `XMLHttpRequest` for sending GET response to server app, i.e. localhost with app's port "http://localhost:8888/getData", but it give a CORS error on Firefox browser.

The script making the request is served via a file:// URL.

I was looking for a lot of information on this issue, but had not found any.
Is there any way to solve it? I don't have any experience in web development and cannot understand correctly some things, but when I write "http://localhost:8888/getData" in address line of browser, it works fine.

Comment: What is the url of the page that is making the ajax request?

Comment: @Taplar I don't know it's url. It is simple .html file that I open in browser

Comment: What do you mean?  When you open it up in your browser, there is some address in the url bar.  What is that?

Comment: file:///C:/ALL/123.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add CORS support.

To enable cross-origin requests in FireFox, Safari, Chrome and IE 10 and later your server must attach the following headers to all responses:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain name

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DAV, content-length, Allow

These headers will enable cross-domain requests in FireFox 3.6+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+ and IE 10+

Comment: Link only answers are considered very low quality and are subject to deletion

Answer (score 2):

The server should be cross origin aware. In java you can use @crossorigin annotation.

Comment: That annotation is not a native Java feature; it's in Spring and possibly some other frameworks, but not all.

Comment: I'm not sure where `java` appears in the question or it's tags

Comment: What is the server in that context? Is this my application? I can't change/rebuild it